# Trying to add to existing value in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table with a name and a number (debt)
what i want to do is when the user inputs a new number to an existing name that number gets added to the initial number, 
it first checks if the name exists, if its not then it `INSERT` a new row - this works -
if the name doesn't exists it should `UPDATE` the existing debt as explained above - and it doesn't work, the update is where i need the help with

right now i'm getting an `SQLiteException` , from what i understand is that the `WHERE` in the update isn't good, tryed a couple ways to fix this but none work, still getting exception

this is the relevant code:
first the method from the `DatabaseHelper` class that the exception points too as the main problem:

```
public boolean updateExistingFriend(String name, String debt, String date) {

    String where = KEY_NAME + "=" + name;

    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_DEBT, debt);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);

    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}
```

this is the method in the main activity:

```
private void updateExistingDebt(String name){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String mydate = df.format(c.getTime());

    String whosDebt;
    Cursor curs = myDb.getByName(name);
    String addedDebt = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex("debt"));

    if (checkFriendDebt.isChecked()) {
        whosDebt = "+" + debtAmount.getText().toString()+ addedDebt +currency.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }else{
        whosDebt = "-" + debtAmount.getText().toString()+ addedDebt +currency.getSelectedItem().toString();
    }


    Cursor cursor = myDb.getExistingDebtName(name); 
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        String frName = friendName.getText().toString();
        myDb.updateExistingFriend( frName, whosDebt, mydate);
        myDb.insertHistory(frName, whosDebt, mydate, debtLabel.getText().toString());
    }
    cursor.close();

    populateListView();
    totalDebts();
}
```

exception in logcat:

```
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Tal (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE maindebt SET date=?,name=?,debt=? WHERE name=Tal
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:897)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:508)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.updateWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1684)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.update(SQLiteDatabase.java:1632)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.barados.myfriendsdebts.DBAdapter.updateExistingFriend(DBAdapter.java:203)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.barados.myfriendsdebts.MainActivity.updateExistingDebt(MainActivity.java:259)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.barados.myfriendsdebts.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:44)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.barados.myfriendsdebts.MainActivity$1$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:196)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4764)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19844)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
10-07 05:24:50.890 26063-26063/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

i think the problem is here:

> String where = KEY_NAME + "=" + name;

but didn't find a better solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very right in thinking that the problem is there. In the specific instance that produced the error, you are apparently dealing with a person named tal.
but

String where = KEY_NAME + "=" + name;

Produces the following

name = Tal

Which is telling sqlite to compare column name, with column Tal which obviously does not exist. You could sorround the name variable with quotes

String where = KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'";

But that most definitely isn't the right answer. The right answer is to modify this part of your query so that it looks like the rest.

String where = KEY_NAME + "=?";

ie use prepared statement and bind the parameter as you clearly appear to be doing for the other fields.

Comment: Great explanation! both ways got rid of the Exception, but only the **String where = KEY_NAME + "='" + name + "'";** actually updated the row,  the "=?" didnt really seem to do anything, not sure what each method means exactly but i will look around about it , anyways thank you :)

Comment: Hope this link will explain about parameter binding https://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/android-sqllite-tip-2-use-compiled-sql-statements/ (using the ? ) usually not using it is not a big issue on android but for web applications with PHP etc, it's always a good idea to use parameter binding.